# How to setup a hook with a view in Drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

So I have a view called "export-spreadsheets". When an admin goes to this page, I want a function to be called so that it basically runs a long SQL query and exports its results to a CSV.

I was wondering where I would add this function to be called?

Thanks.

Comment: You want to export result of views in CSV or result of your custom query ?

Comment: If you are looking to download custom data excelsheet then have a look at my blogpost about it - http://www.drupalconnect.in/download-custom-data-excelsheet-drupal

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom module, add on to the *_menu() hook, make it call the function when you go to a certain url. Have it output the .csv file and `die()`